# Python: printing value in column b for each value in column a

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to use it for my everyday tasks to be good at it.
I want to be able to get values from a csv file and print like the below example. (I am able to read from csv and write to a file the output. Just need the logic to do this.)

```
Name,Item
Andy,Ball
Tom,Car
Zack,Watch
```

output should be:

```
Andy has a Ball
Andy has a Car
Andy has a Watch
Tom has a Ball 
Tom has a Car ... etc.
```

*My code. Ofcourse I edited the actual statements and it may not make sense but that's the code. I did create a function and made the code shorter.

```
import csv

with open('../CSV_Files/File.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    f = open('../Output_Folder/File-1.txt' ,'w')
    for row in reader:
        f.write("Name is %s, network is %s\n" % (str(row['Name']), str(row['Network'])))
    f.close()

with open('../CSV_Files/File.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    f = open('../Output_Folder/File.txt','a')    
    for row in reader:        
        f.write("\n\zone is %s\n" % str(row['Zone']))
    f.close()

print ('Done')
```

Comment: Post the code of how you read the `csv` what data structures you have. Once you have `Andy` and `Ball` , just do `a + ' has a ' + b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the `Name` and `Item` into two lists - `name` and `items`, then you can do below to get the required output.

```
import itertools
name = ["Andy","Tom","Zack"]
items = ["Ball","Car","Watch"]
for i in itertools.product(name,items):
    print(i[0]+" has a "+i[1])
```

**Output:**

```
Andy has a Ball
Andy has a Car
Andy has a Watch
Tom has a Ball
Tom has a Car
Tom has a Watch
Zack has a Ball
Zack has a Car
Zack has a Watch
```

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) provides the cartesian product of the input iterables.

Answer (score 0):

your file doesn't seem to be a a csv file. csv files have a delimiter separating each column, like this:

```
Name,Item
Andy,Ball
Tom,Car
Zack,Watch
```

Your file seems to be a fixed width file, specially how the `C` from "`Car`" aligns perfectly with `B` from "`Ball`" in the line above. Uness you have tabs as separator, and those got converted to spaces in the question?

Anyway, if it was a csv file separated as commas as in my example:

```
with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in cf:
        print('{Name} has a {Item}'.format(**row))
```

If it is separated by tabs, just use

```
cf = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
```

Now, fixed width is harder, because you have to know the width, something like this:

```
with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        name = line[:5]
        item = line[6:]
        print('{} has a {}'.format(name, item))
```

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear in my question. I want the output to print all rows in column B for every roe in column A. Not a one to one mapping instead a 1 to many kinda mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick example. Note you have to set your delimiter as well as skip the first line by using .readline() since your file seems to have headers.

```
import csv

with open('C:\\file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    csvfile.readline()
    for row in reader:
        print(str(row[0]) + ' has a ' + str(row[1]))
```

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear in my question. I want the output to print all rows in column B for every roe in column A. Not a one to one mapping instead a 1 to many kinda mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using python 3.7 and what to output to the same directory

```
import csv
myfile = open("output.txt", "w")
with open('yourfile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')                           
    for row in spamreader:
        mystr = spamreader[i] + "has a "+ spamreader[i+1]
        myfile.write(mystr + "\n")
myfile.close()
```

Comment: Getting the below error.while i != (len(spamreader)-1):
TypeError: object of type '_csv.reader' has no len()

Comment: @onlyninja Sorry yes the reader object does not have a len it extends the iterator object. You should use a for loop instead as fixed in the above code. Let me know if this works :)